# difference between space and geometry

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am confused about the meaning of **geometry** and **space**, there are Euclidean space and Euclidean geometry as well as Riemannian space and Riemannian geometry, but I am confused about the effect of each.
For example, are Christoffel symbols due to space or geometry?
Or can we have a Euclidean space in Riemannian geometry or only some combination between geometry and space is possible?

Comment: "Space" and "geometry" are not technical terms with precise meaning.

Comment: One is an area of Mathematics. The other is a class of objects that mathematicians study. Do you see the difference?

Comment: A space is a set of points or "locations". A geometry is a set of properties that a space might satisfy. So a Euclidean space is a space that satisfies the properties of Euclidean geometry,